# How can a custom class override the btn and btn-danger classes of React-bootstrap without using IDs or !important and by only using classNames

Tags: css, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using React-bootstrap to style my button, But I am unable to override the `btn` and `btn-danger` classes provided by bootstrap. How can I make my class `slotTiming-box-button` override the `btn` and `btn-danger` classes. I want to do this without using ids, or `!important`. I am allowed to use classNames only.

React code snippet

```
 <Button
     className="slotTiming-box-button"
     variant="danger"
      >
Click Me
 </Button>
```

HTML element formed

```
<button type="button" class="slotTiming-box-button btn btn-danger">Click Me</button>
```

An image of the Computed section(in Developer Tools) of the Button is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BHb1DNdh0kA07EF3Qp8quBAp3pFy8GOc/view?usp=sharing).

I have tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59853336/how-to-override-btn-primary-class-in-react-bootstrap-styled-component), but it wasnt much clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS for the custom class...

```
.slotTiming-box-button {
    background-color: #990000;
    border-color: #661111;
}

.slotTiming-box-button:hover {
    background-color: #dd2222;
}
```

https://codeply.com/p/tXdGmQucvD

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue, In my case the `.btn` and `.btn-danger` classes come from `<style>` component as it is visible in the Computed section(in Developer tools) in addition to `bootstrap.min.css`